# SqlDatasource InsertParameter with Where statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqldatasource

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is it possible to use `SqlDatasource.InsertParameter` with the `where` clause?

I would like to insert parameters into partial table where the id is equal to "x". How can I do it?

Comment: Very unclear - can you please show us some code that you have? What exactly are you trying to do? An insert parameter is used to supply a value for an `INSERT` statement, which doesn't have a `WHERE` clause....

Comment: Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    Try
            InciDetailDS.InsertParameters("Description").DefaultValue = txtInciDesc.Text.Trim()
            InciDetailDS.InsertParameters("Action_Taken").DefaultValue = txtActionTaken.Text.Trim()
            InciDetailDS.InsertParameters("Involved_patrons").DefaultValue = txtPatronDesc.Text.Trim()
            InciDetailDS.InsertParameters("FollowUp").DefaultValue = txtFollowUp.Text.Trim()

            InciDetailDS.Insert()

Comment: Thanks Marc. It seems like I cannot write this kind of code, I just need to write a reqular sql statement. I want to insert these above mentioned parameters to the table to "x" patron.

Comment: I have this on aspx page.
    <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Action_Taken" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="FollowUp" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Involved_patrons" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" DbType="Int32" Name="Inci_ID" />
                </InsertParameters>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this. In the select statement I inner joined the two tables(using primary and secondary keys) and then used the where clause by passing the querystring parameter.